# Navigationdrawer view not refreshed when open

Tags: android, view

I have an application which holds a list of notifications.
The notifications are listed in a navigationdrawer.
(i.e. when a user clicks the hamburger icon, the list of open notifications is opened).
The navigation drawer itself is a listview in a swipeRefreshLayout, like you can see in the following code (an user has to pull it down to refresh the notifications):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:gravity="bottom|center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

So far everything is working like expected.
Now I had to implement the scenario to upload offline created notifications.
In my service I send an update broadcast message, which is retrieved by the navigation drawer with the following code (still have to clean it up a bit):

```
private static BroadcastReceiver messageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        //TODO make message for notification service
        if(!LocationService.REFRESH_LOCATION_ACTION_MESSAGE.equals(message)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Got message: " + message);
            notifications.clear();
            notifications.addAll(intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(NotificationService.NOTIFICATION_LIST_ARGUMENT));
            try {
                Collections.sort(notifications, new NotificationComparator());
            } catch(Exception e){
                Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "got notifications: " + notifications);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }
};
```

This part of the code should refresh the view when a notification is created (or send if it was created offline).

When I now send an offline created notification and I wait a bit before opening the navigation drawer, the view is updated and the notification is marked as send.
So this is working fine.

Now the issue:
When I send an offline created notification and I open the navigation drawer directly after the notification is send, the list view is not updated and the notification is still marked as not send (but when I open the notification, it's marked as send).

Is there a synchronization issue or am I doing something wrong here?
It shouldn't make a difference if the view is open or not, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your listview in navigationdrawer by this way

```
public void updateView(int index) {

    if (mDrawerList != null) {

        View v = mDrawerList.getChildAt(index -

                mDrawerList.getFirstVisiblePosition());

        if (v == null)
            return;
        ListView lv= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.left_drawer); //update your data here

    }

}
```

Comment: indeed, data was not updated in this scenario. Thanks